# h2o.deeplearning in R, data structure error

Tags: r, deep-learning, h2o

I want to perform a DNN using the `h2o.deeplearning` function. To do this, we loaded the data using the `as.h2o` function.

I entered the following code to verify that the data was entered correctly, and there were only ten observations. The data has a total of 1,000 observations.

However, when I loaded the data as using `as.h2o` function, only ten data were entered. Which part is wrong?

This is my R code.

```
h2o.init(nthreads = -1, max_mem_size = "5G")
credit<-read.csv("http://freakonometrics.free.fr/german_credit.csv", header=TRUE)
deep_credit<-as.h2o(credit,destination_frame = "deep_credit")

h2o.str(deep_credit)
Class 'H2OFrame' <environment: 0x0000000035bb4ad8> 
 - attr(*, "op")= chr "Parse"
 - attr(*, "id")= chr "deep_credit"
 - attr(*, "eval")= logi FALSE
 - attr(*, "nrow")= int 1000
 - attr(*, "ncol")= int 21
 - attr(*, "types")=List of 21
  ..$ : chr "int"
  ..$ : chr "int"
  ..$ : chr "int"
  ..$ : chr "int"
  ..$ : chr "int"
  ..$ : chr "int"
  ..$ : chr "int"
  ..$ : chr "int"
  ..$ : chr "int"
  ..$ : chr "int"
  ..$ : chr "int"
  ..$ : chr "int"
  ..$ : chr "int"
  ..$ : chr "int"
  ..$ : chr "int"
  ..$ : chr "int"
  ..$ : chr "int"
  ..$ : chr "int"
  ..$ : chr "int"
  ..$ : chr "int"
  ..$ : chr "int"
 - attr(*, "data")='data.frame':    10 obs. of  21 variables:
  ..$ Creditability                    : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  ..$ Account.Balance                  : num  1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 4 2
  ..$ Duration.of.Credit..month.       : num  18 9 12 12 12 10 8 6 18 24
  ..$ Payment.Status.of.Previous.Credit: num  4 4 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 2
  ..$ Purpose                          : num  2 0 9 0 0 0 0 0 3 3
  ..$ Credit.Amount                    : num  1049 2799 841 2122 2171 ...
  ..$ Value.Savings.Stocks             : num  1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 3
  ..$ Length.of.current.employment     : num  2 3 4 3 3 2 4 2 1 1
  ..$ Instalment.per.cent              : num  4 2 2 3 4 1 1 2 4 1
  ..$ Sex...Marital.Status             : num  2 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 2 2
  ..$ Guarantors                       : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  ..$ Duration.in.Current.address      : num  4 2 4 2 4 3 4 4 4 4
  ..$ Most.valuable.available.asset    : num  2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 3 4
  ..$ Age..years.                      : num  21 36 23 39 38 48 39 40 65 23
  ..$ Concurrent.Credits               : num  3 3 3 3 1 3 3 3 3 3
  ..$ Type.of.apartment                : num  1 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 1
  ..$ No.of.Credits.at.this.Bank       : num  1 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 1
  ..$ Occupation                       : num  3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1
  ..$ No.of.dependents                 : num  1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 1
  ..$ Telephone                        : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  ..$ Foreign.Worker                   : num  1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with the print-out of the `str()` function on H2OFrames (reported [here](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4742) a few days ago), not an actual bug.  It shows the correct number of rows at the top of the print-out:

```
- attr(*, "nrow")= int 1000
```

If you use `nrow()` on your frame, you will see the actual number of rows is 1,000:

```
> nrow(deep_credit)
[1] 1000
```

Comment: Then, You mean that it has no problem, right??? Is it just a as.h2o function error? As a result, is there a no problem to use h2o.deeplearning function as this data???

Comment: That's right.  The print-out is wrong (it always says 10 rows even if there are more than 10 rows, which is why we filed a bug to fix that).  You can verify the data size yourself by running `nrow(deep_credit)` or `dim(deep_credit)`.